# Running a c++ file from command line

Tags: c++

I'm very much used to Visual Studio, but a HW assignment requires that the finished product be run from the command line. I've built it in Visual Studio to make sure my code is at least syntactically correct and won't cause any compiler to throw me a message, but he designed the template so that it would only really work on Command Line. Therefore, I need the command line to test the functionality of the code

TL/DR: the jist of it is: I should be able to run it from command line by typing in:

```
programName argument
```

How do I do this with a .cpp?

Comment: Do you mean: `progName.exe arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3` (or however many arguments there are)?

Comment: You need to compile .cpp files first before you can get a runnable program from them. To compile you need to have a c++ compiler installed on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
    Programname.exe argument 1 argument2 ... argumentn
```

Make sure you're running the program in the correct path or specify the full path of the .exe

Comment: Thanks, I had to do a little digging to find the cl command to compile it, but this is pretty much it. I appear to have left in an infinite loop, but this question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

First open command prompt than type `cd` and your file's location ( Bot don't write your program's name.Example we have a test.exe in our desktop. If we open the command prompt we will see something like this:  `C:\Users\Username\ :` We should locate the file so we can do : `cd C:\Users\Username\Desktop` or `cd Desktop` This one works if the directed folder is a sub folder of `Username` .Than you can use this code :    `start test.exe.` hope this helps.Please send a feedback.